# NOPASSWD from local sudoers file is ignored for LDAP account

Tags: sudo, ldap

At work I have Ubuntu 16.04 with LDAP account. I have several NOPASSWD rules in /etc/sudoers.d/gbs configured. They are visible:

```
$ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for m.lewicki on AMDC1494.digital.local:
    env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin, timestamp_timeout=120, env_keep+=http_proxy, env_keep+=no_proxy, env_keep+=https_proxy, env_keep+=HTTP_PROXY, env_keep+=HTTPS_PROXY,
    env_keep+=BUILD_DIR

User m.lewicki may run the following commands on AMDC1494.digital.local:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/mount -o bind /*/* */scratch.*
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/umount -l */scratch.*
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/umount -l -f */scratch.*
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/mkdir -p */scratch.*
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/build
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/cp *.conf */scratch.*/*.conf
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/rm -f */.build.log
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/echo -n
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/chroot */scratch.*
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/chroot */scratch.*
    (root) NOEXEC: NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/updatedb
    (ALL) ALL
```

However they are ginored. For example

```
$ sudo echo -n
```

Still asks for password. I tried adding "sudoers: files ldap" to vim /etc/nsswitch.conf and tried apt-get install sudo-ldap, but neither helped.

Local user account that is NOT managed by LDAP works fine and doesn't ask for password for specified commands.

How to make local sudoers file respected?

Comment: If you run `sudo -l /bin/echo -n`, what happens?

Comment: $ sudo -l /bin/echo -n     gives     /bin/echo -n   and does not ask for password

Answer (score 1):

There is a [known issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/1665322) in the version of sudo that ships with 16.04.  While this did not fix my issue, it's a good place to start.  I included some other possible causes in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309560/configure-sssd-sudo-and-dyndns-update-with-realmd/360294#360294) Unix & Linux answer.  I'm actually still troubleshooting and will document any additional findings there.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thank you for your input. This is more of a follow on comment, not an answer. Next time please add text like this as a comment.

Comment: Not new to SE just Ask Ubuntu.  Comments require 50 rep.